# Bayes: How to use results from a single study to shape data-driven priors

Tags: bayesian, prior

One way to construct informative priors for a subsequent Bayesian analysis is to carry out a meta-analysis of previous studies. Here, substantial research has been done. However, what to do when there is only one previous study that used a frequentist approach? Could we use estimates, and their standard errors, as parameters for a subsequent prior?

For example, I want to use Bayes to perform multilevel confirmatory factor analysis (MCFA). I carried out a previous study that used some of the scales I now want to use at the second level in the subsequent MCFA. Could I then use the standardized factor loadings, and their standard errors, from the first study to determine priors for factor loadings in the second study? In this case, the priors would be based on a normal distribution.

Comment: I do not follow the detail, but in general, it might be better to start with an uninformative prior, treat the earlier study as an observation (if you trust it) which you then use to update your prior, and then use that as the prior for your study

Comment: @Henry; thanks for the comment. Can you point me on anything on how to "update" a prior? Any articles, links etc.? Thanks

Comment: Just found this one: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217593/making-a-bayesian-prior-from-a-frequentist-result?rq=1

Comment: I marked your question as a duplicate of several others. Check also the questions tagged as [tag:prior] for more similar threads.

Comment: I think this seems different than other questions. One answer is to assume a prior for between trial variability based on some relevant information (how much does stuff typically vary between trials, or how much does it vary in the particular area - there's a bunch of publications on that, as well as on meta-analyzing very few trials in rare diseases).